# Change Galaxy Tab 3 from Finnish to English

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Galaxy Tab 3 is showing the Finnish language and I need to change it to English. I can't read Finnish so don't know what choices  to choose to do this. Help.I can get to Settings and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Identify the "Settings" app by its icon (gear), it should read **Asetukset**
- Scroll down and find "Language & Input" (**Kieli ja syöttö**). There should be a globe icon
- Tap on "Language" (**Kieli**)
- Scroll down and find **English**

Comment: Thanks so much for this info. Wife in England couldn't get her tab back to English. Now she has and can message me.